# change all string property max length

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In EF 6 I can do something like this:

```
modelBuilder
  .Properties()
  .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) && 
              p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute), false).Length == 0)
  .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(2000));
```

since EF7 ModelBuilder doesn't have the `Properties()` function, how do I do same thing in EF7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose this to be one of the "still lacking" functionalities in EF Core and expect it to be added in some later version.

Until then, the closest I can suggest (for v1.1.0) is as follows:

```
foreach (var p in modelBuilder.Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string) && p.GetMaxLength() == null))
{
    p.SetMaxLength(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### EF Core 6.0

It has become very simple to set custom defaults  per datatype (like `string`):

```
public class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void ConfigureConventions(
        ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        configurationBuilder
            .Properties<string>()
            .HaveMaxLength(2000);
    }
}
```

(You can override such settings by specifying otherwise for individual properties.)

More info: [pre-convention model configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#pre-convention-model-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I work at a company that had some silly inconsistencies in how booleans are stored as chars in the database.  I created a custom annotation/attribute and wanted to find that for any DbSet that I had set up.

I then created a base DbContext that my contexts inherit from.  It should find any DbSet or DbSet-derived property in an inherited class defined using the `public DbSet<Facility> Foo => Set<FooEntity>();` member syntax.  It iterates through reflection to find any entity properties with my attribute defined.

Below is what I basically did.  Only tested on EF6, don't know if it will work on order versions (sorry).

```cs
public abstract class BaseDbContext: DbContext
{
    protected BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find any DbSets that have properties that implement the Converter attribute
    /// and then assign the converter set up in the attribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
    /// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ReSharper disable once ConvertToLocalFunction
        var isDbSet = (Type? t) =>
        {
            while (t != null)
            {
                if (!t.IsGenericType) return false;
                var d = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (d == typeof(DbSet<>)) return true;
                if (d.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DbSet<>))) return true;
                t = d.BaseType;
            }

            return false;
        };
        
        foreach (var dbContextProp in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propType = dbContextProp.PropertyType;
            if (!isDbSet(propType)) continue;
            foreach (var entityType in propType.GenericTypeArguments)
            {
                var propsWithConverterAttribute = entityType.GetProperties()
                    .Select(p => (p, p.GetCustomAttribute<ConverterAttribute>()))
                    .Where(prop => prop.Item2 != null)
                    .ToArray();

                if (!propsWithConverterAttribute.Any()) continue;
                
                var builder = modelBuilder.Entity(entityType);
                if (builder == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Unable to build model builder entity for {entityType.Name}");
                }

                foreach(var (entityProp, attrConverter) in propsWithConverterAttribute)
                {
                    var builderProp = builder.Property(entityProp.Name);
                    if (builderProp == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(
                            $"Unable to get model builder entity property for {entityType.Name}.{entityProp.Name}");
                    }
                    builderProp.HasConversion(attrConverter!.Converter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyDbContext: BaseDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos => Set<Foo>();
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars => Set<Bar>();

    public FacilityDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [Key] [Column("foo_id")] public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column("active_flag")]

    [Converter(ConverterType.BoolToChar)]
    public bool ActiveFlag { get; set; }
}

public enum ConverterType
{
    BoolToChar,
    BoolToInt
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ConverterAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly ConverterType _type;

    public ConverterAttribute(ConverterType conversionType)
    {
        _type = conversionType;
    }

    public ValueConverter Converter
    {
        get
        {
            return _type switch
            {
                ConverterType.BoolToChar => BoolToCharConverter,
                ConverterType.BoolToInt => BoolToCharConverter,
                _ => throw new Exception("Invalid converter type")
            };
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert MySQL char y/n fields to boolean
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ValueConverter<bool, char> BoolToCharConverter = new(
        v => v ? 'y' : 'n',
        v => v != 'n' && v != 'N'
    );

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert MySQL int fields to boolean
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ValueConverter<bool, int> BoolToIntConverter = new(
        v => v ? 1 : 0,
        v => v != 0
    );
}
```