# Loop/reflect through all properties in all EF Models to set Column Type

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My client has a standard of storing SQL Server decimals with a decimal(13,4) specification. As a result, in a very large and still-growing schema, I have nearly a hundred statements like these:

```
builder.Entity<MyObject>()
    .Property(x => x.MyField1)
    .ForSqlServerHasColumnType("decimal(13,4)");
builder.Entity<MyObject>()
    .Property(x => x.MyField2)
    .ForSqlServerHasColumnType("decimal(13,4)");
builder.Entity<MyObject2>()
    .Property(x => x.MyField1)
    .ForSqlServerHasColumnType("decimal(13,4)");
```

If there is a feature where I can tell EF directly that all decimals should be decimal(13,4) by default, I would like to use that. If not, can I use reflection to loop through every object/property in the model so I can do this in a couple statements?

Something like:

```
foreach(var efObj in EntityFrameWorkObjects)
{
    foreach (var objProperty in efObj)
    {
        if (objProperty is decimal || objProperty is decimal?)
        {
            builder.Entity<efObj>()
                .Property(x => x.efObj)
                .ForSqlServerHasColumnType("decimal(13,4)");
        }
    }
}
```

Reflection seems like a great way to go, because then I can implement some of our other conventions where, if an object has a Name and Description, the Name is required and limited to 256 chars.

**Update:**
I followed the link in Ivan's comment and adapted it to this, which works for me:

```
foreach (var p in builder.Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => 
        p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) ||
        p.ClrType == typeof(decimal?)))
{
    p.SqlServer().ColumnType = "decimal(13,4)";
}
```

Soon after, he provided a full answer, which I changed slightly to work with both decimal and nullable decimal:

```
foreach (var pb in builder.Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => 
        p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) ||
        p.ClrType == typeof(decimal?))
    .Select(p => 
        builder.Entity(p.DeclaringEntityType.ClrType)
            .Property(p.Name)))
{
    pb.ForSqlServerHasColumnType("decimal(13,4)");
}
```

Both approaches work!

**Update 2:** I had to have my objects declared as DbSet<> in the context for the above to work. This didn't seem to be required when I was setting properties line by line.

Comment: See [change all string property max length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427030/change-all-string-property-max-length/41427828#41427828) for something similar in v1.1.0 (can't test in v.1.0)

Comment: Regarding Update 2: The code should be at the end of the `OnModelCreating` after all entity types are discovered, thus including non `DbSet` types, introduced for instance with `modelBuilder.Entity<..>` calls.

Comment: @IvanStoev that makes sense, but I had some `modelBuilder.Entity<..>` statements in there solely to specify the decimal column type, so those statements are gone now.

Comment: You need to have something in order to let EF Core treat your class as entity (it's not reflecting your assembly like EF6). AFAIK it should be either `DbSet`, navigation property referring to entity class (either simple or collection) or `modelBuilder.Entity<..>`. If none of these exists, I don't see how the class will be mapped to a table. Of course the method looks more like workaround rather than a solution like EF6 `modelBuilder.Type<...>` configuration, but are you saying that if you move the procedure at the end of the `OnModelCreating`, it misses some entitities? I'm really interested.

Comment: [The answer is very simple as of EF Core 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922761/5405967).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In EF Core v1.1.0 you can use something like this:

```
foreach (var pb in modelBuilder.Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) || p.ClrType == typeof(decimal?))
    .Select(p => modelBuilder.Entity(p.DeclaringEntityType.ClrType).Property(p.Name)))
{
    pb.ForSqlServerHasColumnType("decimal(13,4)");
}
```

**Update (EF Core 2.x):** Starting from EF Core 2.0, the model is built separately for each database provider, so `HasAbcXyz` methods are replaced with common `HasXyz`. The updated code (which also skips the explicitly configured properties) looks like this:

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) || p.ClrType == typeof(decimal?)))
{
    if (property.Relational().ColumnType == null)
        property.Relational().ColumnType = "decimal(13,4)";
}
```

**Update (EF Core 3.x):** With EF Core 3.0 metadata API changes (`Relational()` extensions removed, properties replaced with `Get` / `Set` method pair), the code is as follows:

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) || p.ClrType == typeof(decimal?)))
{
    if (property.GetColumnType() == null)
        property.SetColumnType("decimal(13,4)");
}
```

**Update (Entity Framework Core 6):** EF Core 6 includes [convention model configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#pre-convention-model-configuration) that can be used to achieve this to all types.
The advantage over looping through entities manually, is that this conventions already ignore certain types (like `Ignore()`, or properties that have Converters).

```
public class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void ConfigureConventions(
        ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        configurationBuilder
                .Properties<decimal>()
                .HavePrecision(19, 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has changed a little, at least for ef core 2.0. Instead of ForSqlServer, you need to use the nuget Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. The extension is named HasColumnType.

Comment: pb.HasColumnType("decimal(13,4)"); would be right if one uses SqlServer

Comment: For EF Core 3.0, they flattened the extension methods. Now use 
if (property.GetColumnType() == null) { property.SetColumnType("decimal(13,4)"); }
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#provider-specific-metadata-api-changes

Comment: @JoshMcKearin Correct. I'm just waiting for 3.0 RTM before posting update (most probably they won't change them from Preview, but one never knows :)

Comment: The RC was released yesterday and can be used in production :D 
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-release-candidate-1/

Comment: could you please update the solution as per @JoshMcKearin  comment because from EF core 3+ RelationalMetadataExtensions has been removed

Comment: @Anjo Sure, here it is.

Comment: For `EF Core 3.x` you need to install the NuGet `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` to get the extension method `SetColumnType`.

Answer (score 8):

### EF Core 6.0

It's now simple to configure defaults for every `decimal` property (or `string`, etc.):

```cs
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder
        .Properties<decimal>()
        .HavePrecision(19, 4);
}
```

More info: [pre-convention model configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#pre-convention-model-configuration)

Comment: nice! was looking for exactly this. I edited you code to actually compile with net 6 now - `HavePrecision` instead of has.

Answer (score 4):

The approach mentioned above does not work when I'm working on EFCore 5.0.1 DB-First. The method below on [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt) works:

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 4)")]
public decimal Numeric { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

New feature will be introduced in EF Core 5.0

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Blog>()
    .Property(b => b.Numeric)
    .HasPrecision(16, 4);
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#preview-4