# Stop autodiscovering of properties and types in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to migrate a large legacy project from EF to EF Core.

We always had rich Entities - with a lot of added functionality in there, instead of simple dead "dataholders".

As we're migrating to EF Core, I notice that there is some 'autodiscovery logic' where it seems to traverse all the entities and properties and tries to include all the related entities and properties it finds into the DbContext. This means that I have to explicitly ignore everything that is NOT database backed.

Otherwise I'll get errors like:

> The entity type 'ActorSource' requires a primary key to be defined. If
>   you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.'

There doesn't seem to be a *direct* property on my Entities with `ActorSource` type, but I assume somewhere it is *leaking* through other properties and the autodiscovery.

Is it possible to turn this around? And to include *only* in the model everything that is specifically marked?

**Disclaimer**

This is a large rather complicated project in the middle of a migration - there's a chance that something else is happening, but as far as I figured out until now it seems to be some kind of *autodiscovery*.

**UPDATE**

For now I'm using something similar like:

```
var entity_types = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().ToList();

foreach ( var type in entity_types )
{
    if ( !type.ClrType.HasAttribute<TableAttribute>() )
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore(type.ClrType);
        continue;
    }

    var entity_type_builder = modelBuilder.Entity(type.ClrType);

    foreach (var property in type.ClrType.GetProperties())
    {
        if ( !property.HasAttribute<ColumnAttribute>())
            entity_type_builder.Ignore(property.Name);
    }
}
```

Note that you have to mark your classes with `[Table]` attribute and your properties with `[Column]` attribute.

Comment: There is no public way to do this yet in a -clean- way (you can work on internal APIs, but that's risky). It's a requested feature (making the conventions public), but no dice yet, that I know of. You can however, at the start of the model configuration, traverse all discovered properties and relations and ignore them, then configure the rest: something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45883622/68972 , but calling `Ignore` instead of `ValueGeneratedXXX` and removing the `Where` clauses from the linq query

Comment: There's a lot of context missing here. Did you have an EDMX, where you had mapped and unmapped properties in the same entities? Are you reusing those entity classes with EF Core now? Can you show an example entity, as well as how it uses the `ActorSource`  type? What have you tried, like `modelBuilder.Ignore<ActorSource>()`?

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster, I indeed have 'rich' entities with a lot of added properties and methods. I am trying to reuse as much code as possible, because the migration is already complicated on itself. Ignore seems to work, but next to the `banana`, I also have to Ignore the `monkey` and the rest of everything growing in the `jungle`.  I think @Jcl answerd my question.

Comment: Hi @Jcl, if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Sure, lemme do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "public" way to do this yet in a -clean- way (you can work on internal APIs, but that's risky). It's a requested feature (making the conventions public), but no dice yet, that I know of.

You can however, at the start of the model configuration, traverse all discovered properties and relations and ignore them, then configure the rest: something like they do in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45883622/68972 (but calling `Ignore` instead of `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` and removing or adjusting the `Where` clause)