# EF CORE How to Change NVACHAR to VARCHAR

Tags: entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework 6.X It was possible to change the default database type by doing this:

`modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("varchar"));`

In EF Core how can i do that?

The method Properties() doesn´t exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop/reflect through all properties in all EF Models to set Column Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468722/loop-reflect-through-all-properties-in-all-ef-models-to-set-column-type)

Answer (score 0):

Since EF Core 6, based on github repository of entity framework ([see here](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/main/entity-framework/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew.md#pre-convention-model-configuration)) :

> previous versions of EF Core (before EF Core 6) require that the
> mapping for every property of a given type is configured explicitly
> when that mapping differs from the default. This includes "facets"
> like the maximum length of strings and decimal precision, as well as
> value conversion for the property type.

In the class that inherits from `DbContext` override `ConfigureConventions`

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(
    ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder
        .Properties<string>()
        .AreUnicode(false)
        .HaveMaxLength(1024);
}
```

Thus all string properties can be configured to be ANSI (instead of Unicode) and have a maximum length of 1024, hence mapping string to `nvarchar` changes to `varchar` when migrations are applied to the database.