# Expression.Convert() not working correctly for datetime datatype in EF Core

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-standard-2.0, ef-core-2.2

In a .Net standard 2.0 project, I'm using *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore* nuget version **2.2.6**. I'm dynamically creating lambda expression like follows:

```
//EntityUtility.ConvertToType() converts string to DateTime type
var constant1 = Expression.Constant(EntityUtility.ConvertToType(minVal, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
var constant2 = Expression.Constant(EntityUtility.ConvertToType(maxVal, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(member.Type) != null)
{
   member = Expression.Property(member, "Value");
}

var exMin = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, Expression.Convert(constant1, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
var exMax = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, Expression.Convert(constant2, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
operation = Expression.And(exMax, exMin);
```

After the query is executed it's failing and throwing error with message `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`. It's converting to wrong datetime format in SQL. Below is a sample of converted SQL for datetime input value:

```
SELECT [user].[username]
FROM [dbo].[user] AS [user]
WHERE (CASE
    WHEN [user].[update_date] <= '2018-03-24T00:00:01.0000000'
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END & CASE
    WHEN [user].[update_date] >= '2018-03-23T00:00:01.0000000'
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END) = 1
go
```

The issue is in the format `2018-03-24T00:00:01.0000000`. The `update_date` is a *datetime* column in SQL Server `user` table.

How can I resolve this issue? Any help is highly appreciated.

**Update**: It's working if the format is `2018-03-24T00:00:01.000`.

Comment: What is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 set to?

Comment: The results in MSSQL Server Mgmt Studio is returning in `2018-03-23 11:14:37.000` format.

Comment: Did you tell EF Core that the column type is `datetime`? e.g. fluently via .HasColumnType("datetime")` or `[Column]` attribute?

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev. It worked after adding `.HasColumnType("datetime")`. Is there  any other/easy way to do so? I'm asking this because there are 1000+ tables and manually I have to add the same for all the `datetime` fields.

Comment: See the link in the answer below. It's for `decimal`, but can be adjusted for `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure EF Core model "knows" that the SqlServer database table column type is `datetime` (by default `DateTime` properties are mapped to `datetime2` type) by using `HasColumnType` fluent API or `[Column`] data annotation - see [Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/data-types) topic in EF Core documentation.

If you need to set this up for many columns, you can use code similar to [Loop/reflect through all properties in all EF Models to set Column Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468722/loop-reflect-through-all-properties-in-all-ef-models-to-set-column-type/41469383#41469383).

Second, it's (almost) always better to parameterize the generated SQL query instead of using constant values (literals). You can do that by wrapping the value in a constant `Tuple` and return an expression referencing the `Item1` property. Something like this:

```
static Expression ToExpression(object value)
{
    if (value == null) return Expression.Constant(null);
    var valueType = value.GetType();
    var closureType = typeof(Tuple<>).MakeGenericType(valueType);
    var closure = Activator.CreateInstance(closureType, value);
    return Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(closure), "Item1");
}
```

and use it instead of `Expression.Constant` in your code. Once you do that, EF Core will create parameters in place of the current literals.

---

Side note: You'll get better SQL translation if you use `Expression.AndAlso` instead of `Expression.And`. The former represents the logical AND (C# `&&` operator) while the later is the bitwise AND (C# `&` operator) which you normally don't use in logical expressions. Same for `Expression.OrElse` vs `Expression.Or`.