# How to change how default precision for Datetime2 in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

By default EF Core code first on MS SQL server generates DateTime columns as DateTime2(7). I want to change default behaviour. When no explicit precision atribute is given than Datetime2(3) should be generated, like [Precision(3)] attribute is used.

Comment: This behaviour (likely by intention) reflects the behaviour of SQL Server, that when you don't define a precision `datetime2(7)` is used. Why don't you want to use an explicit precision? This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Larnu Might be because all the dates in his system are specified to use precision 3. So he wants the default to them be 3 instead of 7 to not forget to specify it somewhere

Comment: How about : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922761/2245256 ?

Comment: I wouldn't like to guess why it is what *they* need, @Irwene . Hopefully *they* will though.

Comment: Not all dates in system, but all dates, that dosn't have explicitly set different precision. Its like 99% of datetimes and yes its because hard to track errors when Precision(3) is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a working solution. I have to use OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime) || property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                if (property.GetPrecision() == null)
                {
                    property.SetPrecision(3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Override this method in your DBContext.

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(
ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
        .HavePrecision(3);
}
```

EDIT:

@MilanBačík is correct.

If you set the precision for your entities using the Fuent API in `OnModelCreating` it overrides the convention. But if you set the precision through data annotations it doesn't.

I believe this to be a bug in EF Core (tested on 6.0)

Comment: That work, but set precision 3 to all datetimes. I want to set it only to ones without explicit Precision attribute.

Comment: @MilanBačík As far as I understand it setting the precision explicitly will override the convention.

Comment: tryed this and still not work - all instancies has precision 3 
var props=configurationBuilder.Properties<DateTime>();
props.HavePrecision(props.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<PrecisionAttribute>()?.Precision ?? 3);